# Java exception: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver.nativeGetVersion()Ljava/lang/String;

Tags: java, exception

I am a java programmer in Korea(South).
I have searched many google articles about these errors.

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver.nativeGetVersion()Ljava/lang/String; thrown while loading gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver thrown while loading gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver

but I haven't solved it yet.

My eclipse build path setting is like this.

I added external jars from 
`C:\dev\java\jdk_6\jre\lib\ext\RXTXcomm.jar`

and Native library location for `RXTXcomm.jar` is
`C:\dev\java\jdk_6\jre\bin\rxtxSerial.dll`

and I`m using springframework

[image: Error]

build has no error.
and Tomcat v6.0 start has no error.

But when I try to use the component from jar,  file error pops-up.

If anyone have a solution please give me a tip.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have fixed English issues with your post.  I also formatted the error message using >

Comment: Thank you!!
But I don`t understand.....Are you saying you fixed wrong expression of my question??

Answer (score 0):

First I checked lib and bin directories of jdk and jre.
There was many RXTXcomm.jar and rtxtSerial.dll in many directories.
So I erased all of RTXTcomm.jar and rtxtSerial.dll.

Then I re-downloaded RTXTcomm.jar and rtxtSerial.dll from
http://fizzed.com/oss/rxtx-for-java
and put then in 
C:\dev\java\jdk_6\jre\lib\ext\RXTXcomm.jar
C:\dev\java\jdk_6\jre\bin\rxtxSerial.dll
and..
C:\dev\RXTXcomm.jar
C:\dev\rxtxSerial.dll

after that
I added java build path in my eclipse.
Project > Properties > Java build path > library tab > add external jar

> select "C:\dev\RXTXcomm.jar" > Native library location > edit
>   select "C:\dev\rxtxSerial.dll"

Finally,
It worked very well.
I think the problem was jar file. I think it was corrupted.

(Sorry My English is not good. I hope you understand what I wrote.)